# How can I bind a callback to a Tkinter resize event without it getting called multiple times redundantly?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback, window-resize

I have a tkinter GUI with a fairly large number of nested widgets. I want to rescale parts of it when the window is resized, so I have bound a callback to a resize event:

```
self.parent.bind("<Configure>", self.onsize)
```

However, whenever the window gets resized, `self.onsize()` is getting called ~100 times, slowing everything down and in a few cases causing a crash after max recursion depth is exceeded. I am assuming that this is because it is getting called as every single widgets gets rescaled individually in the process of resizing the parent window.

How can I set this callback up so that it is only called once, after the parent window and all of the internally linked widgets have been resized?

alternatively, how can I tell from the information contained in the `event` parameter that gets passed, whether or not the event corresponds to the parent window, or to a child of the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am assuming that this is because it is getting called as every single widgets gets rescaled individually in the process of resizing the parent window.

Maybe, maybe not. It depends on what the parent is, and what you're doing in the bound function. If the bound widget (`self.parent` in your example) is the root window or an instance of `Toplevel`, the binding will apply to all child windows. Otherwise, the event will only trigger for the widget it is bound to.

Most likely, your function is doing something to cause the widget to resize while it is responding to the event. This will trigger a new event, and that is why you get a recursion error. In short, you shouldn't be doing something in the bound function to cause the widget which received the event to change size.

> How can I set this callback up so that it is only called once, after the parent window and all of the internally linked widgets have been resized?

One solution is to have the bound function schedule another function to be called once tkinter is done redrawing, using `after_idle`. Whether this will work in your specific case is hard to say since your question doesn't show why you're actually doing. If your function is itself calling `update` or `update_idletasks` it probably won't work since those functions process idle events.

> alternatively, how can I tell from the information contained in the event parameter that gets passed, whether or not the event corresponds to the parent window, or to a child of the parent?

The `widget` attribute of the event object will tell you which widget received the event.

Comment: Yes, it seems you're right - resizing is causing other resize events to spawn from that one in some cases, and it blows up. Sorry for the lack of detail - I'm a bit deeper into this than I should be for the problem I'm having so a MWE will be tricky. I will work on it.I tried the `after_idle` route with no luck. I suspect I'm just doing this fundamentally wrong to begin with, it may be time to refactor to not have to deal with this.